# Can anyone please help explain why document loads sometimes but doesn't other times?

Tags: vb.net, pdf

The code is supposed to grab one or more links, grab the contents of that link(s) and load them into pdf.  For the most part, it works.

The issue we are having currently is that sometimes document or documents are loaded correctly into the PDF; sometimes, the same document that loaded correctly a minute ago will either load blank into pdf or the image portion of the document is not loaded.

I thought that by adding `Response.Clear()`, the original load will flush out and document is ready to load again.  That hasn't been the case so far.

```
Protected Sub btnGetCheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Dim doc As New PdfDocument()

    Dim baseLink As String = _
        "http://default.html?mode=print&ino=pan&s=g"

    For Each r As GridViewRow In dsParcels.Rows
        If CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("link"), CheckBox).Checked Then

            Dim url As String = baseURL & "&gen=" & r.Cells(1).Text
            HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc)

            ' Setup HttpResponse headers
            Response.Clear()
            Response.ClearHeaders()
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        End If
    Next
    doc.Save(Response.OutputStream)
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
End Sub
```

Can anyone suggest what's going wrong?

Comment: You are using Adobe for you PdfDocument?   If so the problem could be that it is a shared instance and you get cross talk if more than one process uses it.

Comment: Why do you call `Response.Clear()` on each consecutive document?

Comment: 1) note that you don't use your baseLink string in your code. 2)so it is ConvertUrl is charge of 1) loading the web page 2)convert it to pdf and 3)append it to the pdf document. Is it synchronous ? What happens if an error happens here ? Are you sure it always load correctly the pdf ? Is the moon really yellow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kenny, you add your documents one-by-one, but every time you call `Response.Clear()` which resets response buffer (removing the already generated PDFs).